# Disable toolbar scroll inside coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have a toolbar that scroll with the content in my app. When I perform an action, I want the toolbar to show always.

So I start with:

```
    appBarLayoutParms.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL);
```

If I scroll on the view, the toolbar hides, it works fine. Then, I perform the action when the toolbar is hidden. I do:

```
  appBarLayoutParms.setScrollFlags(0);
```

After that the toolbar doesn't appear, it remains hidden.

I want to be able to disable the scroll behaviour any time and show the toolbar, and turn it on again after that.

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
...>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            ...
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"                
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"             
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your xml file

Comment: Sure, I have edited my question.

Comment: you did not post your whole xml. But what i understood by your xml file that you are using coordinator layout inside the scroll view. use your toolbar out of scrollView then it will not hide.